# Valgrind is Telling me there are bytes allocated on my heap?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, valgrind

```
   int main(){
    int *pointer = malloc(5);
    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}


 ==44611== 
==44611== HEAP SUMMARY:
==44611==     in use at exit: 22,223 bytes in 183 blocks
==44611==   total heap usage: 259 allocs, 76 frees, 28,335 bytes allocated
==44611== 
==44611== LEAK SUMMARY:
==44611==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==         suppressed: 22,223 bytes in 183 blocks
==44611==
```

So as you can see from the code,there seems to be allocs and frees which i haven't done and a lot of bytes which have been allocated? Are these bytes now unusable by the computer,since i forgot to free them when i started programming in C?
Also what does suppressed mean?
And help to fix this issue.Thanks

Comment: Give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657337/what-do-the-suppressed-leaks-mean-in-valgrind

Comment: Ive read that and it doesn't really answer my question.The bytes allocated keep increasing everytime i run i program that mallocs without freeing.So its different from the link you just sent.Thanks

Comment: Memory should be given back under any modern Operating System on program termination, and even if it was not, I'm at a loss to see how a different execution could know about previously lost memory. Please build a minimal set of test code to replicate the problem and add it to your question so we can experiment and see what's up.

Comment: @user4581301 probably should of done that,sorry,thanks

Comment: Are you on Mac OSX by any chance?

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, post code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still exhibits the problem.  The posted code is missing (at least) one #include statement.

Comment: note, the byte count passed to malloc() should be a multiple of the size of the pointer variable.  in this case, suggest: `int *pointer = malloc(5*sizeof(int));`.   This is mostly to avoid certain problems, like allocating less memory than is actually needed

Comment: per the linked question: 'The error-checking tools detect numerous problems in the system libraries, such as the C library, which come pre-installed with your OS. You can't easily fix these, but you don't want to see these errors (and yes, there are many!) So Valgrind reads a list of errors to suppress at startup. A default suppression file is created by the ./configure script when the system is built."   Did you go through the  configuration step when setting up valgrind?